# Using Environment Variables for Per Environment Configuration in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an iOS application that uses a pretty normal multi-environment deployment model. We have a QA, Prod, and "Dev" version of the app that all talk to their own corresponding backends. I am new to iOS development but am familiar with Node, Java, and a few other development environments.

The first thing I reached to for this problem was Environment Variables. I saw that XCode had a way to set environment variables in a Scheme and they could be read pretty easily. So I used 4 environment variables per environment to configure a few needed backend hosts. Everything seemed to be going fine until I realized that those environment variables seem to ONLY be available when running the app through XCode. Is that correct? Is there no way to configure environment variables that "bundle up" with an app? If so, the ability to configure environment variables at all seems like a footgun.

What I mean is, In a NodeJS or Java app, I can set a number of useful "necessary" configs like a backend hosts and use some approach to provide those values when running the app for real. It seems like in iOS / Swift, environment variables are only useful for development-time debugging settings? The asymmetry between what's available in XCode vs a "real" shipped app seems odd.

Is there a similar standard way that I can configure my app for multiple different environments that works on shipped applications and ideally just involves reading some value at runtime rather than using conditionals and/or using compiler flags or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  The Environment Variables are only meaningful when executing the Scheme in Xcode.  Their primary use in that context is to activate debugging features that are not on all the time.  For example, if you try to create a bitmap Core Graphics context (CGContext) with an invalid set of parameters, the debugger may tell you to set an environment variable to see additional debugging output from Core Graphics.  Or you can set environment variables to turn on memory management debugging features.

When you are running an application on a server, the Unix framework in which the application is running is part of the "user experience".  In that context it makes sense for the application to use things like environment variables.

As developers we understand that a mobile app is running inside a unix process, but that unix environment is mostly unavailable to us.  A similar feature that is common to Unix apps is command line arguments. An iOS application on startup receives command line arguments (`argc` and `argv`) but there is no way specify those when the app is launched either.

There are a number of places you could include configuration information like that which you describe in your application.  The most common that I can think of is to include the setting in the applications `Info.plist`.  At runtime you could access the contents of the property list by fetching the main bundle and asking for it's infoDictionary:

```
let infoBundle = Bundle.main.infoDictionary
let mySetting = infoBundle["SomeSetting"]
```

When the application's info.plist is created, it DOES have access to the environment variables declared in the Scheme so you could put the environment variables in the scheme, reference them in the Info.plist, and retrieve them at runtime from the main bundle.

Comment: The .plist files seem to be a pretty good solution for what I was trying to do. Thanks. I wasn't able to get the environment variables interpolating into the plist file and then "baking in" to the final bundle. But that wasn't a super hard requirement for me and could've been PEBKAC. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try Using FeatureFlags, maybe will help you, check this

https://medium.com/@rwbutler/feature-flags-a-b-testing-mvt-on-ios-718339ac7aa1